# Why Ionic response as an error in geolocation permits?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile, geolocation, ionic-native

I'm working with [Ionic Geolocation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) and debug on mobile app "[Ionic DevApp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/)".

The problem is when I accept permissions for use my GPS, later response as error `PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED`. I was try resolve searching in web ([Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionError) and [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/)) but don't correct my error.

My code:

```
    // onSuccess Callback
    // This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
    // current GPS coordinates
    var onSuccess = function (position) {
      alert('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
        'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
        'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
        'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
        'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
        'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
        'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    function onError(error) {
      alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

¿Why don't accept my permissions?